# WP_Query based on excerpt content

Tags: wordpress

Trying to pull post type according to their excerpt value.
my code so far:

```
$ids = array(111,333,9061);

$args = array (
    'post_type' => 'kb',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array (
            array(
        'key' => 'excerpt',
        'value' => $ids,
        'compare' => 'IN'
            )
    )
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

If I remove the meta_query it pulls the posts.
Also tried with `'key' => 'post_excerpt'`

Any ideas?

Comment: You have the ids in the excerpt?

Comment: it's a long story :) yes, it was imported from another CMS, and the old IDs saved as the excerpt.

Comment: then maybe `post_excerpt` as key, and `'compare' => 'LIKE'`